# hide certain category from single post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to limit number of categories display in a single post on wordpress using this script

```
    function swift_list_cats($num){
$temp=get_the_category();
$count=count($temp);// Getting the total number of categories the post is filed in.
for($i=0;$i<$num&&$i<$count;$i++){
//Formatting our output.
$cat_string.='<a href="'.get_category_link( $temp[$i]->cat_ID ).'">'.$temp[$i]->cat_name.'</a>';
if($i!=$num-1&&$i+1<$count)
//Adding a ',' if it’s not the last category.
//You can add your own separator here.
$cat_string.=' | ';
}
echo $cat_string;
}
```

But I also need to hide some categories. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is to return a new count not based on the length of your array so

```
for($i=0;$i<$num&&$i<$count;$i++){
```

**becomes:**

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
```

**or use** `$temp = array_slice(get_the_category(), //ofset 0, //length 10);`

[Array slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) info can be seen here.

If you need to hide some values, this would be far easier to do by adding a hidden column to your database and select values WHERE hidden = 0. However to address your question.You need to know which values you want to hide. Store these in an array and do the following.

```
        function swift_list_cats($num){

    $hiddenArray = [12, 105];

    //change offset and limit to what you desire removing the slashes and labels

    $temp = array_slice(get_the_category(),  0,  10);
        $count=count($temp);

    $cat_string = '';   

    for($i=0;$i<$num&&$i<$count;$i++){

        if(in_array($temp[i]->cat_ID, $hiddenArray)){
              continue;
        }

        $cat_string.='<a href="'.get_category_link( $temp[$i]->cat_ID ).'">'.$temp[$i]->cat_name.'</a>';

        if($i!=$num-1&&$i+1<$count)

            $cat_string.=' | ';
    }
    echo $cat_string;
}
```

$hiddenArray is the array you populate with your category IDs that you want hidden

Comment: how to use it? i ned for example hide ctagory 12 and 105

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress

Comment: recopy code please. $cat_string needed to be set first. If there's any issues now, the issue is bigger than this code.

Comment: now there is no error but category in single post was not hide :(

Comment: contact me via my email on my profile and i can investigate further.

Comment: add_filter( 'get_the_categories', 'remove_category_link' );

function remove_category_link( $categories ) {

    if ( is_admin() ) 
        return $categories;

    $remove = array();

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

    if ( $category->name == "category name" ) continue;
    $remove[] = $category;
    }
    return $remove;
}    solved usign this thanks :9